# Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus a point homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus any other point?

Tags: general-topology

The title basically, i think I know to approach it intuitively but I am still not sure, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just take the translation map that takes this point to that point. Restriction of it to $\mathbb R^2$ minus this point is a homeomorphism onto $\mathbb R^2$ minus that point.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $X$ is a topological space, $f:X\to X$ a homeomorphism and $a\in X$ any point, then $X\backslash\{a\}$ is homeomorphic to $X\backslash\{f(a)\}$ via restriction of $f$.

So all you need to know, is that in case of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and any two points $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^2$ there is a homeomorphism that maps $a$ to $b$. Such spaces are called homogenous by the way. This homeomorphism can be defined as:

$$f(x)=x-a+b$$

Note that the same homeomorphism works for any $\mathbb{R}^n$.